# ActiveAdmin checkboxes and batch actions unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Checkboxes don't show and the batch actions dropdown is grayed out for all my ActiveAdmin pages.  My `admin/dashboard.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

  menu :priority => 1, :label => proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }

  content :title => proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do
    div :class => "blank_slate_container", :id => "dashboard_default_message" do
      span :class => "blank_slate" do
        span I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.welcome")
        small I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.call_to_action")
      end
    end

  end # content
end
```

An example `Admin.register`, `Votes`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Vote do
  permit_params :ip_address, :weight, :response_id

  index do
    column :response
    column :weight
    column :ip_address
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :response
      f.input :ip_address, :as => :string
      f.input :weight
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Gemfile entry: `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add `selectable_column` so there's a way to select records to apply a batch action on:

```
index do
  selectable_column
  # your columns here
  actions
end
```